# How to generate the first n terms in the series:

Tags: r, tidyverse

the tidyverse way? (say n=10)

[image]

I thought `lag` would be helpful, but I couldn't get correct results.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem which could be vectorized, since it depends on previous results, doesn't it?

Comment: @loki I guess you are right. I wonder what is the suggested way to do it in r. Back to for loops?

Comment: working on it. just a sec

Comment: What is wrong with pre-allocating a vector and populate it through a loop? I'm genuinely trying to understand why people shy away from this basic R functionality?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Nothing is wrong. I am just looking for the faster way to generate terms of series like this, and I wonder if there is a fast, tidyverse way.

Comment: @Brani Keep in mind that the focus of `tidyverse` functionality is usually not efficiency and performance but code readability and syntax consistency. As Roman pointed out, replacing entries of a (pre-allocated) vector in a `for` loop will be very fast.

Comment: If you want to lift some heavy code, you will probably need to go into doing it with C++. As to readability and consistency of the tidy code... Let's agree to disagree. :)

Comment: Fair enough @RomanLuštrik :-) For what it's worth, I've tried my luck at an `Rcpp` solution below (still a very beginner at `Rcpp`).

Comment: @MauritsEvers great, I hope it makes it worth while. Computer time is cheap. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is slightly different option

```
f <- function(a1 = 1, n = 10) {
    ret <- numeric(n)   # Pre-allocation
    ret[1] <- a1
    for (i in 2:length(ret)) ret[i] <- 5 * ret[i - 1] + 3 ^ (i - 1)
    ret
}
f(n = 10)
#[1]       1       8      49     272    1441    7448   37969  192032  966721
#[10] 4853288
```

Two small comments:

1. We initialise the vector with `numeric(n)` which is faster than doing e.g. `rep(0, 10)`.
2. The rest is just a classic `for` loop that starts at the second index of the return vector.

Or a C++ solution using `Rcpp`

```
    library(Rcpp)
    cppFunction("
    IntegerVector f2(int n = 10, int a1 = 1) {
        IntegerVector ret(n, a1);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            ret[i] = 5 * ret[i - 1] + pow(3, i);
        }
        return ret;
    }")
    f2(10)
    # [1]       1       8      49     272    1441    7448   37969  192032  966721
    #[10] 4853288
```

And a `microbenchmark` comparison

```
    library(microbenchmark)
    res <- microbenchmark(
        R_for_loop = f(n = 10),
        Rcpp_for_loop = f2(n = 10)
    )
    #Unit: microseconds
    #          expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
    #    R_for_loop 3.226 3.4195 3.78043 3.4945 3.5625 29.365   100   b
    # Rcpp_for_loop 1.913 2.0980 2.36980 2.2560 2.3495 12.582   100  a


    library(ggplot2)
    autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a classical for loop approach. Since you need to access results from the iteration before, this might be the appropriate way to go.

```
library(dplyr)
t <- tibble(k = 1:10, a = NA)

for (i in 1:nrow(t)){
  if (i == 1){
    t[i, "a"] <- 1
  } else {
    t[i, "a"] <- 5 * t[i - 1, "a"] + 3 ^ t[i - 1, "k"]
  }
}
t
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#        k       a
#    <int>   <dbl>
# 1      1       1
# 2      2       8
# 3      3      49
# 4      4     272
# 5      5    1441
# 6      6    7448
# 7      7   37969
# 8      8  192032
# 9      9  966721
# 10    10 4853288
```

Comment: Modified version, dropping "k" column:  f4 <- function(a1 = 1, n = 10) {
    n=10; e=1; 
    t <- tibble(.rows=n, a = NA) 
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(t)){
      if (i == 1){
        t[i, "a"] <- 1
      } else {
        e <- 3*e
        t[i, "a"] <- 5 * t[i - 1, "a"] + e
      } #else
    } 
    return(t)
  }
  
  f4(n=10)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `vapply` for this

```
# Init
len <- 10L + 1L
init = 1L
x <- numeric(len); x[[1]] <- init
# Create sequence
vapply(2:len, function (k) x[[k]] <<- 5*x[[k-1L]] + 3^(k-1L), numeric(1))
# Result
x
# [1]        1        8       49      272     1441     7448    37969   192032   966721  4853288 24325489
```

Answer (score 2):

Tidyverse solutions: slower than "for_loop", & "vapply" methods

```
library(tidyverse)

# f31 is slightly faster (using function) instead of formula (on f32)
f31 <- function(a1 = 1, n = 10) {
  x <- c(a1,rep(0,n-1))
   map_dbl(2:n, function (k) x[k]  <<-  5*x[k-1] + 3^(k-1))
  return(x)
} #func 

f31(n=10)
# [1]       1       8      49     272    1441    7448   37969  192032  966721
# [10] 4853288

f32 <- function(a1 = 1, n = 10) {
  x <- c(a1,rep(0,n-1))
  map_dbl(2:n, ~ {x[.]  <<-  5*x[.-1] + 3^(.-1)})
  return(x)
} # func 

f32(n=10)
# [1]       1       8      49     272    1441    7448   37969  192032  966721
# [10] 4853288
```